# Sudo apt-get update doesn't work - no packages installed

Tags: official-repositories, add-apt-repository

[image]How to add default packages in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

but without nano or vim or any other software....
my server is naked only 600 MB with swap.

and which repositories to add???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and choose everything you need.  Click `Generate List` at the bottom. You can add each line to the `sources.list` file without editing by typing in:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "full line of repository from generated list" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

repeat the line above for each line from the generated list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks although it's now too late....i made a mistake while installing and didn't set this up.....now everything is working fine...but your answer is correct!